# What file size for online Games?

Tags: filesize

Hi All

I am new here and apologise if this has bee asked before, but I was wondering the following.

How big would you have a music file in size?

What MP3 settings would use to achieve this?

What length in minutes would you envisage each song/music section to be?

I have a 12-minute file and at the moment is at 4.7mb but I would like it as small as possible. I was thinking of cutting it up into sections and getting the person that is coding it to loop the parts but mp3's I don't think like that!!!!

Any help would be fantastic

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Ask the programmer. They will be able to tell you for sure, everyone here can only speculate. Don't feel like you're bothering them, it's a completely reasonable thing to ask.

Max size, file type, compression can be hugely variable.

Answer (score 1):

It really really varies. And your programmer is going to be the one to answer it. Every game on a different platform is going to be different.

It used to be audio would get 10% of resources (RAM, disk space, CPU...) but even that changes and has never been constant.

And yes, MP3 does not like to loop. It pads files to fit the block size it needs which is just enough to cause ticks. Ogg does not have the same problems and might be a more viable option if you need to loop music seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys at what sample/bit rate would you export for online games? 